# Building 64bit Live555 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, live555

I am trying to build the components of Live555 with Visual Studio 2013 64bit on Windows 7.

I have tried editing win32config and the *.mak files without success. I've been searching the internet for a few hours and trying all kinds of things with command prompts.

For some reason VS2013 x64 command prompt is still building 32bit static libs and I can't figure out why.

If anyone has any good ideas, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The win32config file that you get from the .tar.gz file requires substantial editing to make it compatible with recent SDK and MSVC++ releases. This is a version that produced a clean build:

```
NODEBUG=1
TARGETOS = WINNT

UI_OPTS =       $(guilflags) $(guilibsdll)
CONSOLE_UI_OPTS =   $(conlflags) $(conlibsdll)
CPU=amd64

COMPILE_OPTS =      $(INCLUDES) $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvarsdll) -I. /EHsc /O2 /MD /GS /D "WIN64" /Oy- /Oi /D "NDEBUG"
C =         c
C_COMPILER =        cl
C_FLAGS =       $(COMPILE_OPTS)
CPP =           cpp
CPLUSPLUS_COMPILER =    $(C_COMPILER)
CPLUSPLUS_FLAGS =   $(COMPILE_OPTS)
OBJ =           obj
LINK =              link -out:
LIBRARY_LINK =      lib -out:
LINK_OPTS_0 =       $(linkdebug) ws2_32.lib /NXCOMPAT
LIBRARY_LINK_OPTS = 
LINK_OPTS =     $(LINK_OPTS_0) $(UI_OPTS)
CONSOLE_LINK_OPTS = $(LINK_OPTS_0) $(CONSOLE_UI_OPTS)
SERVICE_LINK_OPTS =     kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ws2_32.lib -subsystem:console,$(APPVER)
LIB_SUFFIX =        lib
LIBS_FOR_CONSOLE_APPLICATION =
LIBS_FOR_GUI_APPLICATION =
MULTIMEDIA_LIBS =   winmm.lib
EXE =           .exe
PLATFORM = Windows

rc32 = rc.exe
.rc.res:
    $(rc32) $<
```

After you've edited this file, run the genWindowsMakefiles command from bash (or the CMD file). Next, start the x64 Visual Studio Command Prompt. Make sure you got the x64 native configuration flavor of it. Issue the following commands:

```
cd c:\projects\live\liveMedia
nmake -f liveMedia.mak
cd ..\groupsock
nmake -f groupsock.mak
cd ..\UsageEnvironment
nmake -f UsageEnvironment.mak
cd ..\BasicUsageEnvironment
nmake -f BasicUsageEnvironment.mak
cd ..\testProgs
nmake -f testProgs.mak
cd ..\mediaServer
nmake -f mediaServer.mak
```

Alter the first command to match the directory where you put the source.
TODO items: cleaning doesn't work, it tries to use the *nix rf command. Simplest workaround is del *.obj to force the compiler to rebuild the object files
the .exe files are built without a manifest. Shouldn't matter for the test programs, I assume you're only interested in the .lib files
it builds the release version of the libraries and executables, you'll have to tweak the COMPILE_OPTS to get a debug build.

> In order to compile 64 bit native code with Visual Studio 2013, you
>   require professional edition.

Open the VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt
Then make sure you set C_COMPILER to "$(TOOLS32)\bin\amd64\cl" after correcting TOOLS32 to the VC/bin dir.

Comment: when calling nmake -f testProgs.mak, is anyone else getting NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '-out:testMP3Streamer.exe' : return code '0x1'  ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile 64 bit native code with Visual Studio 2013, you require professional edition.

Open the VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt

Then make sure you set C_COMPILER to "$(TOOLS32)\bin\amd64\cl" after correcting TOOLS32 to the VC/bin dir.

Comment: There is `win32config` file you would probably want to check and setup. Also there is [Visual Studio Community Edition 2013](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) if you need Pro features for free.